# Preventing a ddos from incoming SMS

Tags: twilio, sms, twilio-programmable-chat

I am working on an SMS-based service that parses incoming texts and sends a response, building on top of Twilio. I am concerned about a possible ddos which would result in increased costs. Is there a way of preventing this or limiting the number of times a user can send SMS without you being charged? I am based in Australia, so some of the alternatives to Twilio are not available with local numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can monitor inbound activity and if you see a massive influx, you can remove the webhook, as detailed here, which will prevent anymore SMS inbound toward your account.

[Is there a way to block incoming SMS on my Twilio phone number?](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223181648-Is-there-a-way-to-block-incoming-SMS-on-my-Twilio-phone-number-)

Comment: Thanks Alan. The link does answer my question. It would be good if you could be able to whitelist users phone number. This way you are proactively preventing.